# What would be the "medical" term for hitting your head against a brick wall?

Tags: terminology

My Grandfather was a GP from Aberdeen and often took pleasure in explaining how he dealt with time-wasters. The individual would come into the surgery seeking a Doctors note excusing them from work on medical grounds, even though they were clearly fine. Rather than go through the hassle of a confrontation at the surgery, my Grandfather would send the individual on their way with a Doctors note that said they were suffering from "Oscillatory plumbosis". The individual would be happy that they got away with pulling the wool over the eyes of the Doctor and would proudly present the note to their employer. Then, when the employer telephoned my Grandfather to ask what "Oscillatory plumbosis" actually is, he would explain that the individual is [swinging the lead](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/swing-the-lead#:%7E:text=%5BBritish%5D,stop%20anyone%20swinging%20the%20lead.).

In a similar fashion, what medical sounding term could describe "hitting your head against a brick wall"?

Comment: Welcome to MedicalSciences.SE. While your anecdotal intro to your question is quite funny, your question isn't strictly about the sciences of medicine so it is not on topic here. Maybe it might fit in English Language Usage?

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it does not appear to be about a topic described in the [help/on-topic].

Comment: @ChrisRogers Thanks for the vote to move and apologies for getting the wrong stack. I guess Eng Lang is a better fit :)

Comment: This may seem like runaround, but [latin.se] might be a good place to ask, since medical jargon is often based on Latin.

Comment: Or as a start, https://www.wordhippo.com/what-is/the/latin-word-for-8a8fa066fa3914ae2738d930789aef5acd1bf837.html says that "muri fictilis" is Latin for a brick wall. Maybe you could combine that with a fancy term for concussion.

Comment: Recurrent murotic capitopercussive syndrome.

Comment: @ARogueAnt. That sounds like an answer more than a comment ;)